# Hide/show DIVs - change current effect to fade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the code below found on web tutorial to show/hide DIVs. It works great but don't like the effect. Would like the DIVs to fade in / fade out instead (or something smoother, for the moment the DIVs are growing from the top-right corner). How could I adapt the code to do this? Youc ans ee it here http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/w4HWn/1/ Many thanks

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.textzone').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(2000);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(2000);
          }
     });
}
```

Comment: Change `.show() .hide()` to `.fadeIn() .fadeOut()`

Comment: Are you using an each loop just for finding an element with a specific id?

Comment: try to get to know the documentation and the lovely search feature on the site http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Thanks, I tried but this is too technical for me at this stage, but will definitely try to improve my js skills

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change `.hide()` to `.fadeOut()` and `.show()` to `.fadeIn()`

But looking at your example, you could do it much simpler by using data attributes.

Have a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/w4HWn/13/).

You may need absolute positioning or some other technique because the two divs stack up while fading in and out.

Comment: Thanks Moin. Unfortunately that doesn't work, probably for the same reason as why Raminson's code not working either (my site is a single page and each page has a separate div - see the website here http://goo.gl/kPPYB )

Comment: @Greg: See another updated example. The `#` was making the page jump to the top.

Comment: Hi Moin, for some reason your code works in jsfiddle but not on my website. See the site with your updated code: http://goo.gl/kPPYB

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods, you can also minify the code, try the following:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.textzone').fadeOut();
     $('#'+thechosenone).fadeIn();
}
```

---

As you are using jQuery you can use the jQuery `click` handler:

HTML:

```
<div class="source-title-box"><span class="activity-title"><a href="#source-region">Our region</a></span></div>
<div class="source-title-box"><span class="activity-title"><a href="#source-oursource">Our source</a></span></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.activity-title a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
     var thechosenone = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.textzone').fadeOut(600, function(){
         $(thechosenone).fadeIn(600);
    });   
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w4HWn/12/)

Comment: Thanks Ramison. I tried dreamweaver is telling me that your code is not valid and it does not work (if it helps the original code is here http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/w4HWn/1/ )

Comment: Hi Raminson, many thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately that does not work, probably because I'm already using DIVs to navigate between pages (see your code in action here http://goo.gl/kPPYB page "the source")